# using autofac to register different dependencies for particular interface types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

Given the following registration code...
`ILogger` takes a single string parameter as a constructor argument.
`IJob` implementations all take an `ILogger` as a constructor argument.

```
// register the 'default' logger.
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("category", "default"));
```

Lots of registrations clipped out for brevity...

```
// register the 'job' logger. (this is a problem, a duplicate...)
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("category", "job"));  

// register some classes that need a different logger parameter.
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(_ => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(_))
    // how to do this...
    .WithLoggerWithCategoryJob();
```

How do I use the `category=default` logger for all my class registrations except the `IJob` ones.
I would like to use the `category=job` logger for all those.

Comment: Have you looked at a custom IRegistrationSource? See http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know, it looks like it might do the trick.

Comment: I have been hacking away at this for a few hours, and am not sure there's enough context in the IRegistrationSource to accomplish the above. I will keep trying though.

Comment: the IComponentContext and InstanceLookup don't seem to have the host type that is being injected into. I think I need to consider a  different approach, perhaps just using a factory of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution demonstrates how to provide a default parameter for the logger, and to override the logging parameter just for `IRepository<>` implementations.

The code can quite easily be enhanced to provide a set of overrides depending on the implemented interfaces.

```
/// <summary>
/// The logging module.
/// </summary>
public class LoggingModule : Module
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Override to add registrations to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Note that the ContainerBuilder parameter is unique to this module.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="builder">The builder through which components can be registered.</param>
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<NewLogger>()
            .As<ILogger>()
            .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("category", "Default"));
        base.Load(builder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to attach module-specific functionality to a component registration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method will be called for all existing <i>and future</i> component
    /// registrations - ordering is not important.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="componentRegistry">The component registry.</param><param name="registration">The registration to attach functionality to.</param>
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var type = args.Component.Activator.LimitType;
                if (type.GetInterfaces().All(_ => !_.IsGenericType || _.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IRepository<>)))
                    return;

                var pm = new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
                    (p, c) => c.Resolve<ILogger>(new NamedParameter("category", "RepositoryLogger")));
                args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[] { pm });
            };
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```